Why is my render preview different from what the render result?
So currently, I have two problem. The first one is that the result rendered is different from what is shown in the render preview in viewport shading.
Render Preview:

Render Result:

The second problem is it takes a very long time to render. Is there any way the render time can be shorten a little? My computer can't handle such heavy performance. If there is no other way, then I am willing to wait for it to render too.


For time, you can also increase the Noise Threshold in the Cycles Render Sampling data properties to something closer to the Viewport sampling properties. Finding a balance there takes a little tinkering. Use Ctrl+B to select a small render region to play with it.

Look into the Outliner, you need to enable the visibility of the object called Lens for render:

As for the render time you can put a Time Limit in the Render panel but there may be other ways...

I didn't realize I have diasbled the visbility, that is totally dumb of me.
